# One column abstract in two column article on same page as title

Tags: page-breaking

it should be an easy problem but I can't find the error. With those lines, there are two different pages created for abstract and title. I need both on the same page and tried already something like `\nopagebreak`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}               
\usepackage[german]{babel}       

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\twocolumn[ 
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{abstract}        
        ...
    \end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse} 
]
```

Comment: i assume that this \maketitle is causing trouble right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
% twocolproc.tex  SE 581632

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}               
\usepackage[german]{babel}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{The Title}
\author{A. Writer}   

\begin{document}

\maketitle 

\let\oldclearpage\clearpage
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{} % \onecolumn starts with a \clearpage

\onecolumn
    \begin{abstract}        
       This is the abstract text for this document. It should be in one, not
       two columns.
    \end{abstract}
\twocolumn

\let\clearpage\oldclearpage  % restore \clearpage to its normal operation

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The above code didn't work properly as the text of the second column overlapped the text of the abstract. The code below produces a reasonable non-overlapping result.

```
% twocolprob2.tex  SE 581632

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}               
\usepackage[german]{babel}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

% do this to get the original abstract typesetting
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \small
  \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-0.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
  \end{center}%
  \quotation}
  {\endquotation}

\title{The Title}
\author{A. Writer}   

\begin{document}

% twocolumn but with one column text beforehand
\twocolumn[
\maketitle 
    \begin{abstract}        
       This is the abstract text for this document. It should be in one, not
       two columns as it is hopefully here.
    \end{abstract}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot! But there is now the second column overlapping the abstract. would it be better to put some blank lines in? this would seem pretty statical to me..
looks almost like the abstract is put in one column, extended in the second column and the second column overwrites it.

Comment: @GaTe92 I have added a second answer which I think meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I asked my supervisor for some hints and he mentioned mintage.. is this \renewenvironment something comparable? Anyways, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Move `\maketitle` to the proper place:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
  \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
  This is the abstract.
  This is the abstract.
  This is the abstract.
  This is the abstract.
  This is the abstract.
  \end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer necessary. On the other hand, typesetting in German *does* require `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: in the tex I was creating is this causing some errors, but as I created a new one it worked - thanks!